# Best Practices: how to check for NULL return value in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, null

This is a style question for C and C++.  Do you prefer

```
void f() {
  const char * x = g();
  if (x == NULL) {
    //process error
  }
  // continue function
}
```

or this:

```
void f() {
  const char * x = g();
  if (! x) {
    //process error
  }
  // continue function
}
```

? The former is much clearer, but the latter is less verbose.

Comment: In C++11, the first example should be replaced by `if (x == nullptr)`

Comment: in c++, the latter is preferred, but you shouldn't be using raw pointers in C++ in the first place

Comment: Do whatever your team does. Or not. I would expect no one to have trouble reading code with either of those. If I was doing a code review I would wonder why the function is returning a null pointer in the first place, or why it is returning a pointer a character at all but never question the null check itself.

Comment: The former is much clearer only if you are not familiar with the latter.

Comment: At our company you are encouraged to use the former and remove the latter.

Comment: If using `==`, I would check for `NULL == x`, as there's less chance of miss-typing it as an assignment.  If I accidentally miss off an equals, the compiler will complain rather than set `x` to `NULL`.

Comment: Duplicate: *[C/C++ Checking for NULL pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825668)*

Answer (score 5):

It mainly depends on the *adopted convention* within your group of work.

As the `!= NULL` form may be clearer to a developer who is used to it, the inverse is also true for developers who were used to check a `NULL` value using the boolean form.

As *@Andy Prowl* mentioned it, a much clearer version of this appeard in C++11 by the use of the `nullptr` type : `if (x == nullptr)`. This notation should be used as a convention by every members of a team if you are writing C++11 application.

Finally, there exists different patterns that are pretty much used such as the [`Null Object Pattern`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) that avoids making this check everywhere in your code, in case this check involves a specific habit of your application.