# How to check if void pointer points to NULL?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

So if you do:

```
void *ptr = NULL;
```

What is the best way to check if that void pointer is NULL?

My workaround for now is this:

```
if (*(void**)ptr == NULL) ...
```

But this doesn't seem like the best way, as I'm implicitly assuming ptr is of type void** (which it isn't).

Comment: Why so make fuss about it

Comment: Read: [Can I use `if(pointer)` instead of `if(pointer != NULL)`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772103/can-i-use-ifpointer-instead-of-ifpointer-null)

Comment: Workaround for *what*?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Your `ptr` does not *point to* a null pointer, it *is* a null pointer. A null pointer does not point to any object, derefrrencing it is UB.

Comment: If `ptr` is NULL, after casting it will still be NULL, and dereferencing it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd simply write `if (!ptr)`.

`NULL` is basically just `0` and `!0` is true.

Comment: Not on all architectures, you will be writing non-portable code.  It might have been the 286, when using segment addressing, where NULL != 0, but that was many decades ago.

Comment: I would compare ptr with NULL; like ptr == NULL. There is no guarantee that NULL is equal 0.

Comment: Is that approach advisable in the present world, modern machines?

Comment: @jacekmigacz That makes no difference. `ptr == NULL` is same as `ptr == 0` is same as `!ptr`. Even if implementation uses NULL which is not all bits zero, it's still guaranteed that compiler will make all three above behave the same.

Answer (score 7):

Be sure to include a definition of NULL.

```
   #include <stddef.h>

   void  *X = NULL;

   // do stuff

   if (X != NULL)  // etc.
```

If you include `<stdio.h>` and similar then `stddef.h` gets pulled in automatically.

Finally, it is interesting to look at the definition of NULL in `stddef.h` and by doing this you will see why your initial guess at what to do is interesting.

Answer (score 2):

A NULL pointer is a pointer that isn't pointing anywhere. Its value is typically defined in `stddef.h` as follows:

```
#define NULL ((void*) 0)
```

or

```
#define NULL 0
```

Since NULL is zero, an `if` statement to check whether a pointer is NULL is checking whether that pointer is zero. Hence `if (ptr)` evaluates to 1 when the pointer is not NULL, and conversely, `if (!ptr)` evaluates to 1 when the pointer is NULL.

Your approach `if (*(void**)ptr == NULL)` casts the `void` pointer as a pointer to a pointer, then attempts to dereference it. A dereferenced pointer-to-pointer yields a pointer, so it might seem like a valid approach. However, since `ptr` is NULL, when you dereference it, you are invoking undefined behavior.

It's a lot simpler to check `if (ptr == NULL)` or, using terse notation, `if (!ptr)`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you're right of course, and I've edited accordingly. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

If your code manages to compile when assigning `void *ptr = NULL`, then it stands to reason that a simple `if` statement to compare if it is `NULL` should suffice, particularly because `NULL` would have to be defined if the code can compile.

Example of sufficient way to check:

```
if(ptr==NULL)
{
    rest of code...
}
```

I wrote a little test program, compiled with gcc on linux, which works:

```
int main()
{
    void *ptr = NULL;
    if(ptr==NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That couldn't compile without a `#include` for one of the several standard headers that define `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old post, but wanted to add something that might be useful.

What I usually do is something like this,

This is my function.

```
void MyMethod(  const void* l_pData  ///< Source data
              , size_t l_nLen        /**< Number of bytes to convert */) {
    // Return if nothing is provided
    if (l_pData == NULL || ((const char*)(l_pData))[0] == '\0' || 0 == l_nLen) {
        return;
    }

    // Rest of the code
}
```

You can check for

```
 - Null data
 - Empty data
 - Invalid length
```

Following are validated

```
MyMethod("", 10);
MyMethod(" ", 10);
MyMethod(NULL, 10);
MyMethod("valid", 0);
```

Comment: This is C question. C doesn't have `reinterpret_cast`.