# while(foo) vs while(foo != NULL)

Tags: c, while-loop

Can someone explain how `while(foo)` vs `while(foo != NULL)` are equivalent? Also:

`while(!foo)` vs `while(foo == NULL)`

I know that ! is not, but that is about all I know.

Comment: If `foo` is a pointer, then the definition of `while(foo)` is `while(foo != NULL)`. Therefore they are equivalent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use if (pointer) instead of if (pointer != NULL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772103/can-i-use-if-pointer-instead-of-if-pointer-null)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `foo` is of pointer type, `while (foo)` and `while (foo != NULL)` are exactly equivalent. Both are also equivalent to `while (foo != 0)`. (In my opinion `while (foo != NULL)` more clearly expresses the intent.)

In any context requiring a condition (`if()`, `while()`, a few others), the expression is treated as *true* if the condition compares unequal to zero, *false* if it compares equal to zero.

`NULL` is a macro that expands to an implementation-defined *null pointer constant*. Comparing a pointer value to `NULL` yields a true value for a null pointer, a false value for any non-null pointer.

The constant `0` is a null pointer constant [*]. (This doesn't mean that a null pointer has the same bit representation of `0x00000000` or something similar, though it often does; it means that a constant `0` *in source code* can denote a null pointer.) As you'd expect, comparing a pointer value to a null pointer constant tells you whether that pointer is a null pointer or not. In `while (foo)`, the comparison to zero is implicit -- but it still tests whether `foo` is a null pointer or not.

More generally, `while (foo)` compares `foo` to `0`, which is equivalent to comparing it to "zero" of the appropriate type. `while (foo)` is always equivalent to `while (foo != 0)`. For a floating-point value, it's also equivalent to `while (foo != 0.0)`. For a character value, it's equivalent to `while (foo != '\0')`. And, as we've seen, for a pointer value, it's equivalent to `while (foo != NULL)`.

(In C, a comparison operator always yields an `int` value of `0` if the condition is false, `1` if it's true -- but any non-zero value is treated as true, via the implicit inequality comparison to zero.)

[*] A *null pointer constant* is defined as an integer constant expression with the value `0`, or such an expression cast to `void*`. A null pointer constant isn't necessarily of pointer type, but *converting* it to pointer type yields a null pointer value. Comparing a pointer value to `0` causes the `0` to be implicitly converted to the pointer type so the comparison can be done.

Comment: @chux: Updated. (`0` is both an expression of type `int` and a null pointer constant; I can see that might cause confusion.)

Comment: Yes it did for me and I enjoying a lunch of [crow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_crow).  It turns out `#define NULL 0` can be valid as so can `#define NULL ((void*)0)`.  The latter has advantages, but both are compliant.

Comment: @chux: There's an obscure argument that `#define NULL ((void*)0)` is not valid. (N1570 6.5.1p5 doesn't say that a parenthesized null pointer constant is a null pointer constant.) But in practice it's certainly intended to be valid.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(foo);
```

and

```
while(foo != NULL)
```

Are equivalent simply because NULL is a macro that expands to either `0`, or `(void*)0` or `0L`, given that in C 0 evaluates to false(and any non-zero number to true) then

```
while(foo); //while foo isn't 0
while(foo != NULL) //expands to while(foo != 0) < while foo isn't 0
```

Comment: Depends on type of `foo`.  Consider `double foo`.  `while(foo);` is OK, yet `while(foo != NULL)` does not compile: "invalid operands to binary `!=`" depending on how `NULL` is defined which should be a null pointer constant and not `0` as suggested here.

Comment: @chux Sure, this is assuming `foo` is either a pointer or an `int` however `NULL` is guaranteed to compare equal to 0, in practice I think most implementations do use 0 as `NULL`.

Comment: "most implementations do use 0 as NULL"  Disagree, My gcc 4.9.2 uses `#define NULL ((void *)0)`.  MS Visual 2010, when compiling as `C` uses `#define NULL    ((void *)0)`. Perhaps you are thinking of how `NULL` is defined in another language like `C++`.

Comment: @chux I said that in my answer "NULL is a macro that expands to either 0, or (void*)0 or 0L"

Comment: I assert `NULL` can be `(void*)0`, but not `0`, nor `0L`.  Your answer states it could be `0, or (void*)0 or 0L`.  You comment "most implementations do use 0 as `NULL`", is not backed by any example versus 2 counter examples given.

Comment: @chux what I meant by "do use 0 as. NULL" is "do use some form of 0, either (void*)0, 0 or 0L as NULL", read http://c-faq.com/null/long0.html, as for "most implementations use 0 as NULL", I never tried to pass that as a hard fact

Comment: Per chat with a3f concluded `NULL` may be either `0` or `(void *)0`  - I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

while (`expression`) repeats the enclosing block as long as `expression` evaluates to any non-zero value. When `expression` evalutes to 0, the while loop ends.

An `expression` that's a pointer type is considered to be non-0 if the pointer value is not `std::nullptr`, or `NULL`.

The `!` operator is a boolean `not` operator.

Therefore

```
 while (foo)
```

And

```
 while (foo != NULL)
```

are logically equivalent to each other. Therefore, the logical inverse of the two are also equivalent to each other.

Comment: `std::nullptr` is a c++ thing. We're in a __[c]__ question.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is a *symbolic constant*, you can think of it as a sort of replacement text. `NULL` is just something that the compiler later replaces with a zero, so writing `while (foo != NULL)` is the same as writing `while (foo != 0)`. Remember, `==` says yes if what's to the left of it is equal to what's to the right of it, whereas `!=` says yes if what's to the left of it is NOT equal to what's to the right of it.

In C, the number 0 always means false and every other number means true. So `while (foo != 0)` is the same as saying "Run the code in this loop while foo is true". `while (1)`, for example, is the same as saying "Run the code in this loop forever", because 1 is a number that is always different from zero and hence is always true.

In C, if you use just `foo` where a true-or-false kind of value is expected, it's the same as saying `foo != 0`, that's kind of like a shortcut you can use, it's the same as asking "is foo true?". `!` means "not", so asking `!foo` is the same as asking "is foo NOT true?", in other words "is foo false?". This means that `while (!foo)` is the same as "Run the code in this loop while foo is false", which is the same as `while (foo == 0)` since zero means false, which is the same as `while (foo == NULL)` since `NULL` means zero.

Think of it like this: the code in a loop will only run if what's in the parenthesis is true (that is, non-zero). So in `while (foo)` the computer will ask "is foo non-zero?", if yes the loop keeps going. Now, if you have `while (!foo)`, the computer will ask "is foo NOT non-zero?", if yes the loop keeps going. The loop only stops when the expression in the parenthesis results in false.

`NULL` is defined in several standard header files, it's not a keyword like `if` and `while`, you need to include a header file that defines it to be able to use it. The idea is that when a pointer points to address zero, it's called a "null pointer", that's why it's called `NULL`, it's used when you want to say "zero the address" rather than merely "zero the number".

**Edit:**
As correctly pointed out by Matt McNabb, `NULL` may be defined as `0` or as `(void *)0`. To stay clear of any doubt, I quote the C11 standard:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type **void ***, is called a *null pointer constant*.

And later on

> The macro **NULL** is defined in **<stddef.h>** (and other headers) as a null pointer constant; see 7.19.

Then, in Section 7.19:

> 3 The macros are
>
> **NULL**
>
> which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant; and
>
> **offsetof**(*type*, *member-designator*)
>
> which expands to...

And the text goes on. So `(void *)0` and `0` are valid implementation-defined null pointer constants.

Comment: `NULL` may be either `0` or `(void *)0`.

Comment: @Matt McNabb Can `NULL` be `0`?  As I read C spec, `NULL` is a "null pointer constant".  `0` is an `int`.  Maybe same value, but differing types and sizes.

Comment: @chux it then goes on and defines `null pointer constan`t on being an integer constant that equals zero or the same cast to `void*`.

Comment: @a3f My ref for "NULL which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant" is form C11 §7.19 3. Where is the "...on being an integer constant that equals zero ..."?

Comment: @chux C11 n1570: §6.3.2.3p3. Of course the implementation is free to choose a value apart from all bits zero to represent `NULL`, it's required though to treat the integer `0` as `NULL` when in a "pointer context".

Comment: @a3f Agree about "treat the integer `0` as `NULL`" in a "pointer context", but that does not mean "defines `null pointer constant`  (`NULL`) being an integer constant" in your earlier comment. To be clear, `NULL` not only has a value, but a type.  As I read the C spec, that type is some pointer and `0` is not a pointer.

Comment: `"An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant"` == `"defines null pointer constant on being an integer constant that equals zero or the same cast to void*"`, at least to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74114/discussion-between-chux-and-a3f).

Comment: @danieltm64 Concluded with a3f that Matt McNabb is correct with `NULL` may be either `0` or `(void *)0`.

Answer (score 0):

a while loop can run like so:

```
while(1) //This will run forever.

while(true) //This will run forever.
```

`NULL` is like 0, so if you have `while(foo != NULL)`, this is saying that while(foo is not equal to 0, so while it is equal to 1 or something else) run it.