# difference between if(pointer) vs if(pointer != NULL) in c++, cpplint issue

Tags: c++, pointers, coding-style, cpplint

I already checked this post [Can I use if (pointer) instead of if (pointer != NULL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772103/can-i-use-if-pointer-instead-of-if-pointer-null) and some other posts on net.

But it is not stating any difference between two statements.

**Problem:** As I run cpplint.py on my cpp code, I found issues where I check pointers for NULL.
I preferred to check using simple

```
if(pointer)         //statement1
```

but **cpplint** says you should check like

```
if(pointer != NULL)        //statement2
```

So I just want to know , Are there any benefits of *statement2* over *statement1* ? Are there some scenarios in which *statement1* may create problem ?

> **Working:** As per my knowledge there is **no difference in working** of both statements. Its just a change of coding style.
>
> I prefer to use like *statement1*, because
>
> - Its Simple, Readable
> - No Tension of missing (`=`) by mistake over equality(`==`) in a comparison

But cpplint is raising this as issue, then there might be some benefit that I missed.

**Note:** Java also doesn't support *statement1*.

Comment: Why tag [C] if question is "difference ...in c++ ..."?  ... and then mention [Java]?

Comment: I added [C] because this question is also valid in C. I mentioned java, because I just wanted to provided information that How other languages handle this scenario.

Comment: The question may be valid in many other languages such as `C`, but the _answer_ details are different.  Better answers come with specifying a single target language.

Comment: Yes you are right. Question s should be asked to target single language only. But in this particular case ansers details to both c & c++ are same. Is not it ? Thats why i tagged C too.

Comment: No, they answers can differ.  The details and nuances of `NULL` and `if (ptr)` are subtle enough in one language, let alone two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, if `pointer` is really a pointer type there is no difference, so everything here is a question of coding style. Coding style in turn depends on habits in different communities so there can't be a general recommendation.

I personally prefer the first because it is shorter and more to the point and avoids the use of the bogus macro `NULL`.

In C `NULL` can be very different things (integer or pointer) and in C++ its use is even deprecated nowadays. You should at least use `nullptr`, there.

Comment: It can be very different things (int and pointer), but cannot be very different other things (`std::optional<>`, empty container / string, etc.). We're sort of missing a `nothing_t nothing` conceptually, sometimes I feel.

Comment: @lorro, I was clearly talking about C in that phrase.

Answer (score 3):

You are using Hungarian notation, where it's possible to tell if a variable is a pointer. As long as it is - either native or smart - there's no difference. However, when someone changes it to another indirect type (e.g., `std::optional<>`), then the *second* will fail. So my suggestion is to keep on using the first: it's not Java, it's C++.

Comment: That code is **not** using Hungarian notation. Hungarian notation uses **prefixes** to indicate types.

Comment: Ok, the idea is that you can tell the type from variable name.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, assuming `ptr` is a pointer, the comparisons `if (ptr)` and `if (ptr != NULL)` are functionally equivalent.

In C++11 and later, it is often considered preferable to use the alternative `if (ptr != nullptr)`.

For a simple check of a pointer, the differences in these options are really stylistic.  The mechanisms might differ slightly, but the end result is the same.

cpplint, like most automated checkers, tends to - by default - complain more about breaches of some style guidelines more than others.  Whether any particular set of guidelines is right or wrong depends on what is needed for your project.

For class types that can sensibly be compared with a pointer (e.g. smart pointer types) the preferred test depends on what set of operations (comparison operators, implicit conversions, etc) that type supports.

Answer (score 1):

In `C`, onsider  :

```
int *ptr=malloc(10*sizeof *ptr);
free(ptr); // though the memory is freed, the ptr is not auto-set to NULL
if (ptr)
{
printf ("ptr is not null\n");
}
```

So you are expected to put

```
ptr=NULL; // ptr is explicitly made to point at nothing
// The above step is mandatory.
```

after the `free`.

So as a response in the the `if-statement`, one might recommend to do

```
if ( ptr == NULL ) // This is mostly a coding style & improves readability?
```

or better

```
if ( NULL == ptr ) // less chances of error
```

Well, the [[ site ]](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cpplint) says about `cpplint`that it is  :

> <sup>*An automated checker to make sure a C++ file follows **Google's C++ style** guide*</sup>

So again, it is somebody's style that matters. Say , if you contribute to somebody's code in google, they expect you to follow this style where it facilitates easy collaboration.

Comment: Yes, Why google is following second statement over first, that is the question actually

Comment: `Why` cannot be answered imho, i just wanted to say, if you're contributing to some google-code projects, you need to(ie  'must') follow this style for your code to be accepted.

Comment: @ashish : Also, i follow this style in (some) case/s as mentioned in my example where it is easier to understand what is going on, if(ptr != NULL) makes me literally say `is the pointer not equal to null`?

Answer (score 1):

There is one scenario that may create a problem using *statement1*.

Consider the following code which could have two different meanings.

```
bool* is_done = ...;

// Is this checking if `is_done` is not null, or actually
// intended to check if `*is_done` is true?
if (is_done) {
  ...
}
```

If you intended to do a null check, you're fine. But if your original intent is to check if `*is_done` is true but missed an asterisk by accident, this code may result in a totally unwanted behavior and require you to spend X hours to figure out the culprit.

This could've avoided by explicitly checking the statement like

```
// Now this results in a compile error and forces you to write
// `*is_done` instead.
if (is_done == true) {
  ...
}
```

This is applicable to any types that could be implicitly converted to `bool` like std::unique_ptr.

Someone may argue that the above case is too rare and still prefer the `statement1` in favor of simplicity. I think it is fair and both styles are acceptable. But some organizations, like Google, may encourage you to follow their coding style to keep the lesson they previously learned.

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference between both if(pointer) and if(pointer != NULL). if(pointer) is used for the code optimization.