# Can you use strcmp() to check for nullptr value?

Tags: c++, oop

Is this piece of code any good to check if a pointer or variable hold a nullptr value?

```
if(strcmp(variable/pointer, nullptr) == 0){
    Do something cool
}
```

I'm trying to work on some code and I want to know the best way to check if there is a nullptr value present.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Comment: I've considered. I'm new to C++ and still a baby in C.

Comment: @Mekanic I think [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) is a good reference. For example, here's the entry for [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp). Its two parameters must be pointers to null-terminated strings.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thanks.

Comment: So you considered it and didn't do it. Why not? And what does being a baby have to do with it?

Comment: @EJP What is your problem?

Comment: @Mekanic It's not personal. In general it's expected that people will check documentation and do some debugging before posting questions. You'll help yourself and ask better questions when you're really stuck.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Ok well I respect that... Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is

```
if (!pointer || !variable) { 
    // do something cool
}
```

`!pointer` is essentially the same thing as `pointer == nullptr` and is considered by some to be better style.  See [Can I use if (pointer) instead of if (pointer != NULL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772103/can-i-use-if-pointer-instead-of-if-pointer-null)

`strcmp` is meant to be for C string comparisons.   https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm

Comment: Does that check for the same thing as using strcmp()?

Comment: `strcmp` is meant for c-string comparisons, if you want to check if the pointers are pointing to null (or that the pointers are `nullptr`) then you want to do what I said

Comment: Ok, now does that deserve a downvote if your new to C++?

Comment: @Mekanic I did not downvote.. I don't downvote without giving sufficient explanation for the downvote

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `strcmp` to check whether a variable is equal to `nullptr`. From [`strcmp` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp):

> **Parameters**
>   lhs, rhs   -   pointers to the null-terminated byte strings to compare

Not only do the input arguments to `strcmp` need to point to byte strings, they must point to null-terminated byte strings.

Besides, you are making things may more complex than they need to be. You can just use:

```
if ( variable != nullptr )
{
    // Do something
}
else
{
    // Do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp()` has undefined behaviour if either argument is a null pointer.   Therefore it is necessary to check for null before calling `strcmp()`.

For example, to only call `strcmp()` if both intended arguments are not null

```
 if (first && second && !strcmp(first, second))
 {
      // first and second are both non-null, and contain matching strings
 }
```

or (more verbosely, C++11 and later)

```
 if (first != nullptr && second != nullptr && strcmp(first, second) == 0)
 {
      // first and second are both non-null, and contain matching strings
 }
```

In C++, you'd be better off using the `std::string` type, rather than messing around with arrays of `char`, string termination, and functions like `strcmp()`.