# Check if a pointer is NULL and it causes a runtime error

Tags: c++, pointers

I am doing the leetcode question https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/

Definition of a ListNode is:

```
 // Definition for singly-linked list.
 struct ListNode {
     int val;
     ListNode *next;
     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
 };
```

When I check if a list is hit the end, I used:

```
int v1 = h1 == NULL? h1->val:0; // h1 is defined before: ListNode* h1 = l1;
```

But it returns a **runtime error**, but if I changed it to

```
int v1 = h1? h1->val:0;
```

it is accepted.

**Why is that?**

Comment: Check that condition again... It might be clearer if you try to turn it into a normal `if-else` statement.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825668/c-c-checking-for-null-pointer as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This line of code:

```
 int v1 = h1 == NULL ? h1->val : 0;
```

Is more or less identical to:

```
int v1 = 0;
if (h1 == NULL)
    v1 = h1->val;
```

Note that if `h1 == NULL`, then you will exhibit **undefined behavior** when you dereference `h1` in the following line.

Answer (score 1):

You need != instead of == as Null tends to be zero or false

Comment: Do you mean there is a logical error in that particular code, or is it a general statement?