# What is the most efficient way to test if a pointer is null?

Tags: c++, performance, pointers

What is most efficient between the two ways of testing pointer nullity : `if(pointer==NULL)` or `if(!pointer)`.

```
MyObject* p;
[...]

// Solution 1
if ( p )
{ // Do something
}

// Solution 2
if ( p!=NULL )
{ // Do something
}
```

Comment: I **highly** doubt they compile to different assembly.

Comment: @BoBTFish I have no doubt. I can just try. https://godbolt.org/g/cCrgUb

Comment: According to me, what i have used in our project both works same.It depends on your code requirement which if condition you want to be satisfied according to what you want to be executed if, if satisfies to true.And most importantly make sure your pointer initialise to NULL before you use it further in If.

Comment: @NickyC They didn't mention a compiler, cpu architecture, OS, optimisation options...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It makes no difference what so ever. It's purely a style issue what you prefer.

By the way, you should use `nullptr` rather than `NULL` if you use C++11 or later.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer `if (ptr)` because:

1. It is short and clear
2. It doesn't depend on `NULL` keyword. Which have to be `nullptr` on C++11 or later as [Jesper Juhl mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41180120/7285157).
3. From [SoapBox's comment on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3825704/7285157):

> They are compatible with C++ classes such as auto_ptr that are objects that act as pointers and which provide a conversion to bool to enable exactly this idiom. For these objects, an explicit comparison to NULL would have to invoke a conversion to pointer which may have other semantic side effects or be more expensive than the simple existence check that the bool conversion implies.

Answer (score 1):

Those are same. It makes no change in your program whatever you use.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather prefer the `if (p!=NULL)` as it prevents form accidental errors like casting the `p` in other thing, like an `int` for instance, between the declaration and the use of it.

Here the compiler should warn as int differ form `NULL` (initially `NULL=(void*)0`)

Furthermore i prefer to declare like this :

```
MyObject* p=NULL;
```

because you cannot assure that `p` wont have a value different of zéro. If you miss to instantiate it between declaration and use.

And it is less misleading than the 
`if (p==NULL){} else {}` which may occur in an accidental assignment (only one =)

Off course in the **C++11** or later this could involve some changes in your code even if the call of `NULL` is still working but deprecated.