# What is the difference at runtime between !a and a == nullptr in the real world?

Tags: c++

When I am checking whether a pointer is `nullptr` in my code, I would like to use `if (a == nullptr)` since it make more sense to me. However, I see most senior programmers and tutorial codes like to use `if(!a)` instead. I know what it means, but this way is just not as straight-forward as the former one for me. I just wonder, will these two ways of `if` checking cause big a runtime difference in real world projects, like when we need to use this `if` statement thousands of times?

Comment: Alternative duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365127/c-difference-between-pointer-and-pointer-nullptr and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180094/c-what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-test-null-pointer

Comment: Only the second of @user17732522 's suggestions addresses this question (the run-time impact), so I've updated the link give in the close reason.

Comment: the generate the same code. Its a matter of style choice, in some places the code reads better one way as opposed to the other