# How to check for NULL pointer in C?

Tags: c, strcmp, null-pointer, argc

I have a homework in C for this semester, and the teacher said I should write this function not that complicated. 
I'm new to programming, and I can't seem to find the answer. He said we did some of this type of stuff in class, but I couldn't find anything like this.

```
int checkforerror(int argc){
    if (argc != 3) {
        fputs("Too little or too many arguments!\n", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Also he pointed out, that I have to check for nullpointer in a function. I found some nullpointer check in some programs which we wrote in class, but I'm not sure it's good this way.

```
int mycmp(char *s1, char *s2){

    if (!(s1 && s2))
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

So we did something like this in lessons.
Also I tought about this:

```
if (s1 == NULL && s2 == NULL)
   return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

I don't really know whether they are really null pointer checks and which should I use.

Can you please help me with these?

Comment: `if (s1 == NULL && s2 == NULL)
   return EXIT_FAILURE;` **-->>** `if (!s1 || !s2 )
   return EXIT_FAILURE;`

Comment: I believe what you seek was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825668/checking-for-null-pointer-in-c-c).

Comment: The most readable version is `if (s1 == NULL || s2 == NULL)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [De_Morgan's_laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

> (not (A and B) = not A or not B)

Your condition

```
if (!(s1 && s2))
```

is the same as

```
 if (!s1 || !s2))  //same as if (s1 == NULL || s2 == NULL)
```

Here you are checking if any of `s1` or `s2` is `NULL` and if so you exit.

---

But in second one

```
if (s1 == NULL && s2 == NULL)
   return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

if both `s1` and `s2` are `NULL` then you are exiting.

If any of `s1` or `s2` are not `NULL` you will proceed further and will try to access them, thus invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return `EXIT_FAILURE` when **any** of the pointers is `NULL`, use the first option, i.e.,

```
if (!(s1 && s2))
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

If you want to return `EXIT_FAILURE` when **both** pointers are `NULL`, use the second option, i.e.,

```
if (s1 == NULL && s2 == NULL)
   return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

The actual value of `NULL` is implementation defined. So it is better not to perform logical operations that assume the value of `NULL` to be a particular value.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete other answers, it seems you are confused with the definition of **null** pointers (and perhaps pointers at all).

Briefly going through those two points: A **pointer**, in C, is a variable that points to another "object". More specifically, a **pointer** is a variable that stores a memory address, in which you have some other data. Check [[1]](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm) for more examples. 
A **null** pointer, in the context of pointers, indicates that a **pointer variable** is pointing "nowhere" [[2]](http://c-faq.com/null/null1.html). This is generally used to distinguish whether you are pointing to some **valid** (i.e., not null) or invalid (i.e., null) data.

Comment: Now one must also distinguish wild- and dangling-pointers from those. And you probably meant *object* instead of *"variable"*.

Comment: Indeed for both your remarks! On your first point, I tried to provide a *short* answer as the question was not *well-defined* (even though those are important concepts to solve his doubts).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have said about using `if (s1 == NULL || s2 == NULL)`, I also wanted to make mention of the next line i.e. the `return EXIT_FAILURE`. I'm not sure why you are doing this.

[`EXIT_FAILURE`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/EXIT_status), and `EXIT_SUCCESS` are macro constants usually used with the [`exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) function to indicate failure or success (respectively) of a program. Returning them in a function which looks like it is doing string comparison, just doesn't make sense. Do you even know what the value of those constants are? `EXIT_SUCCESS` *may* be zero, but what is the value of `EXIT_FAILURE`

You should consider using values that actually make sense for that function i.e.

- `0` for equal
- `1` if `s1` is greater than `s2`
- `-1` otherwise.