# Why isn't my if catching this null pointer dereference?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm working with a kernel module, which is causing a null pointer dereference when inserted. I've tracked the error down to [this function](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/base/swnode.c#L439) in swnode.c (not part of the kernel module, but is called by the module):

```c
static struct fwnode_handle *
software_node_get_next_child(const struct fwnode_handle *fwnode,
                 struct fwnode_handle *child)
{
    struct swnode *p = to_swnode(fwnode);
    struct swnode *c = to_swnode(child);

    if (!p || list_empty(&p->children) ||
        (c && list_is_last(&c->entry, &p->children)))
        return NULL;

    if (c) {
        c = list_next_entry(c, entry);
        if (c->node)
                pr_info("child node named %s\n", c->node->name);
    } else {
        c = list_first_entry(&p->children, struct swnode, entry);
    }

    return fwnode_handle_get(&c->fwnode);
}
```

I added the `pr_info("child node named %s\n", c->node->name);` call for debugging, and that line causes the null pointer dereference. Prior to that the error was with `return fwnode_handle_get(&c->fwnode)` which caused an oops complaining I was executing things in NX memory; it's apparent that c->fwnode is NULL, so I can try to work out why that is, I'm just wondering why my debug print caused an error too.

This situation confuses me; I'm explicitly checking that `c` and `c->node` are **not** null, in a way that I thought should protect against this kind of error (based on answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825668/checking-for-null-pointer-in-c-c)). The dereference operations are against c (because, by my understanding, `c->member` is equivalent to `(*c).member`) and `c->node`. So; why, given the `pr_info` call should only be evaluated if `c` and `c->node` are **not** null does it cause a null pointer dereference?

EDIT:

Close voters need to read both question and threads more carefully. This issue is **not** caused by a typo. The missing curly braces in the original example (which has since been edited to include them) are **not** the cause of the issue.

Comment: You are missing curly braces after `if(c)`. Otherwise the `if(c->node)` should not be indented

Comment: You don't check `c->node->name` at all. It can still be `NULL` even if `c->node != NULL`.

Comment: @Gerhardh agreed, but that's not a null pointer dereference; in that case I'd just expect the string to print out "child node named (null)" - at least that's what usually happens

Comment: Why would you expect to print `"(null)"` if you pass a `NULL` pointer? There is no requirement for `printf` to check before derefencing the pointer you pass for `%s`. Some libraries do it, but they are not required to do.

Comment: @Gerhardh that's just the behaviour I've seen so far. I'm not especially au fait with C.]

Comment: That's the problem. "This is what normally happens" sometimes is the entry into world of **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: @Gerhardh fair enough, I'll test that.

Comment: @Gerhardh so if I do `if (c->node->name) {pr_info("passed\n");}` it does throw the error on the if. That being the case though...how can I do a null pointer check to prevent the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220911/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-dan-scally).

Comment: You posted code with an obvious bug, and received an answer pointing out that obvious bug. The proper way forward would be to (probably accept that answer and) ask a new question with corrected code and a question about any remaining bugs. Now you have moved the goalposts so that the answer you got is no longer valid. This reduces the incentive for others to answer, too - what if you change the question again once they find a bug in your code?

Comment: This is one of the reasons we always insist on a [mre] - hopefully you could reduce the code in your next question to only have a single bug, or, even better, discover the solution yourself while working out which part isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: @triplee I disagree with your characterisation of the events here, but if you don't feel like answering that's entirely your prerogative.

Comment: I disagree with reopening this but closing it again is probably not feasible. You will probably have a better experience if you try to adhere to this site's rules and philosophy.

Comment: FWIW: I cast the third Reopen vote on this question and, at the same time, edited out your comment that was addressed to the "Close Voters." I then had second thoughts, and rolled back the edit, so that the context was more apparent. I raised the issue in SOCVR, where there was a brief conversation.

Comment: That conversation has now been moved the the chatroom created here.

Comment: I suspect that the mystery of the null dereference shall be revealed by placing a breakpoint at the offending line, then inspect all involved variables in your favourite debugger. For example, perhaps `c->node->name` is NULL?

Comment: @Gerhardh thanks again for your help in the chat; you were right. The value of `c->node` is not null but is also not a valid memory address. Weirdly the `IS_ERR` macros don't seem to actually catch it (when I print it, it shows the value 3 rather than a negative number, which is presumably why. No idea what it is in that case!); but regardless I'd happy for the explanation as to what was happening. Post an answer for a green tick.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details, i.e. what module code looks like that makes it go to this function? And what is the source of the properties (DT, ACPI, swnode, ...)?

Comment: @0andriy I can, but I'm going to open a new question for that. The chappie above spotted why the null ptr dereference was happening, so I think that closes this one and I'll make a new one for "why is this null to begin with"

Comment: Please, do. And don't forget to provide necessary information, such as Linux kernel version in use and if there were patches applied, esp. if they affect the area in question.

Comment: @0andriy yep, will do

Answer (score 4):

Your code

```
if (c)
    c = list_next_entry(c, entry);
    if (c->node)
            pr_info("child node named %s\n", c->node->name);
else
    c = list_first_entry(&p->children, struct swnode, entry);
```

is equivalent to

```
if (c) {
    c = list_next_entry(c, entry);
}
if (c->node) {
    pr_info("child node named %s\n", c->node->name);
} else {
    c = list_first_entry(&p->children, struct swnode, entry);
}
```

Therefore, `c->node` will be evaluated regardless of whether `c` is `NULL`.

Add braces to have the check for `c` work.

```
if (c) { /* add a brace */
    c = list_next_entry(c, entry);
    if (c->node)
            pr_info("child node named %s\n", c->node->name);
} /* add a brace */
else
    c = list_first_entry(&p->children, struct swnode, entry);
```

Comment: argh. Thanks. My instinct is to always brace ifs, but then I see people skipping them and feel like I should too :P

Comment: Anyhow; braces added, no dice. I still get the error.

Comment: In that case, most likely `list_next_entry` is returning `null` and making `c` null, so `c->node` causes the error?

Comment: @Fred I have checked that with `if (!c) {pr_info("c is now null\n");}` and that printout never appears.

Comment: @Fred It's a circular list with a head (non-element) node. `c = list_next_entry(c, entry);` will not set `c` to `NULL` but the result will only be valid if the original `c` was not the last element on the list. But this code is not reachable in that case due to earlier checks in the function (the `list_is_last()` call).