# C++ Adding 2nd Element to BST - Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, insert, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

So I built a BST based off of the example in class. My peers' trees all work fine, however, I am getting a segmentation fault when I add a second element. I have isolated the error coming from this line - 'if(current->left == NULL){' I am not sure why it is resulting in a segmentation fault and how to avoid it. I will leave the related insertNode code as well as the Node class as I feel it might be a problem there.

```
template <class T>
void BST<T>::insertNode(T value){
  TreeNode<T> *node = new TreeNode<T>(value);


  if(isEmpty()){
    cout << "Is root" << endl;
    root = node;
  }else{
    cout << "Is not root" << endl;
    TreeNode<T> *parent = NULL;
    TreeNode<T> *current = root;
    cout << "Starting Loop" << endl;
    while(true){
      parent = current;

      if(value < current->key){
        cout << "less tahn" << endl;
        //Left
        current = current->left;
        cout <<"left" << endl;
        if(current == NULL){
          //we found our location/insertion point
          cout << "Found Spot" << endl;
          parent->left = node;
          break;
        }
        cout << "Not NULL" << endl;
      }
      else {
        //Right
        cout << "Right" << endl;
        current = current->right;
        if(current == NULL){
          //we found our location/insertion point
          cout << "Found Spot" << endl;
          parent->right = node;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the treeNode class -

```
template <class T>
class TreeNode{
  public:
    TreeNode();
    TreeNode(T k);
    ~TreeNode();

    T key;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
};
template <class T>
TreeNode<T>::TreeNode(){
  left = NULL;
  right = NULL;
}

template <class T>
TreeNode<T>::TreeNode(T k){
  left = NULL;
  right = NULL;
  key = k;
}
```

Comment: before you check if `current->left == NULL` you should check if `current == NULL`

Answer (score 1):

This builds upon what SHR said. When you execute the line `current = current->left`, there is a chance that `current->left` of the previous current is `null`.

This means that when you perform the check `if (current->left == NULL)`, it will result in segmentation fault because there is no `left`.

You can rewrite the conditional to be something like:

```
if (current && !current->left){
...
}
```

By doing so, you check to see first if `current` is not null, and if it is, only then will it look at the left pointer of the node. Or you can just check before hand to see `if (current)`.

It is also fully sufficient and encouraged to check for `NULL` by performing `if (node)` instead of doing `if (node == NULL)`. This explains why: [Checking for NULL pointer in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825668/checking-for-null-pointer-in-c-c)

Comment: Thank you! This is a lot of very helpful information. I substituted in the code you gave, but I am still having some troubles though. Now, it simply skips over the if statement, as it is not true now. Fair enough, however, if there is no current - it should insert the node to the tree instead of aborting the insert. Should I put the current = current->left AFTER the if statement? It seems to work, but I am not sure if the tree is holding its structure correctly. Thank you!

Comment: EDIT - just tested it and it does not seem to insert anything. Is the root not storing correctly if current is set to root?