# What is meant by asking if the pointer that points to an array is true or false?

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, boolean

I'm quite new to programming and have been looking at a few example codes, I would just like to know what is meant by the `if(!pi)` statement in this code.

```
// allocate and populate array
    int* pi = new int[N];
    if (!pi)
        return 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        pi[i] = rand() % 100000;
```

Comment: `!pi` <=> `pi == nullptr`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking for NULL pointer in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825668/checking-for-null-pointer-in-c-c)

Answer (score 6):

Pointers are implicitly convertible to `bool`. If the pointer is null, then the result is `false` and otherwise `true`. operator `!` is the logical NOT operator.

In this case the check is redundant, because `new[]` will never return a null pointer and therefore the condition is never true.

Comment: For illustration, GCC eliminates the check and the corresponding branch under optimizations: https://godbolt.org/z/7T4hfb.

Comment: Thanks for the help.